# Threading functions and Tkinter Progress Bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function called analyze in another py file that reads a file and does some different analysis on the data based on the type of experiment. I am trying to make a GUI for this program where users select the file (filename) and the type of experiment from a drop down menu (NOT used as of yet) then run the analyze function based on their inputs.

I wanted a progress bar to show up when they click the run button so the users know its doing something and then disappear when it's done. I have the GUI working this way with some test code that is called when Run is clicked. Now I just need to make it so that analyze is called when Run is clicked. I understand I need to do this with threading. But I tried threading the analyze function nothing happens, as in analyze isn't run and the progress bar doesn't show up/the Run button isn't disabled. Sometimes I get the error:

analyze() takes 1 positional argument but 42 were given

I'm sure it is something I don't understand about how threading works.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog , messagebox, ttk
import time
from threading import Thread
from Analysis import analyze


filename=""

def browse():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    Name.config(text=filename)

def run():
    Run.config(state="disabled")
    bar=tk.Frame(window)
    bar.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=10)
    pb=ttk.Progressbar(bar, orient="horizontal",mode='indeterminate', length=500)
    pb.grid()
    pb.start()
#    for _ in range(50):
#        time.sleep(.1) # simulate some work   #code used to test the GUI
#        pb.step(10)
#        pb.update_idletasks()
    run_thread()
    pb.stop()
    bar.destroy()
    Run.config(state="normal")

def run_thread():
    Thread(target=analyze, args=filename).start()


window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("750x150")

window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

lbFrame=tk.LabelFrame(window, text="Select a file")
lbFrame.grid(column=0,row=0)
button1=tk.Button(lbFrame, text="Browse", command=browse)

button1.grid()

Name=tk.Label(window)
Name.grid(column=1,row=0, sticky="W")

Select=tk.Label(window,text="Select Experiment :")
Select.grid(column=0, row=1)

var=tk.StringVar(window)
var.set("Blood")

dropdown=tk.OptionMenu(window,var,"Blood","Multi Blood","Multi Urine")
dropdown.grid(column=1, row=1,sticky="W")

bottom=tk.Frame(window, height=850)
bottom.grid(column=1,row=3)

Run=tk.Button(bottom,text="Run", bg="green", command=run)
Run.grid()
Run.config(width=25)



window.mainloop()
```

and analyze is basically

```
def analyze(filename):
     #do some stuff
```

Comment: I don't think you need threading for the progressbar, ttk handles it already. You just need to throw in the value it increments every time the function is progessing.

Comment: What value? There is no predetermined time the function will take or steps which is why I'm using a indeterminate progress bar

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with

> analyze() takes 1 positional argument but 42 were given

stems from a formatting mistake.

should be

```
def run_thread():
    Thread(target=analyze, args=(filename,)).start()
```

then I at least got your code to run. Can't say anything about the progressbar, as I don't know, which kind of data your function is returning. Maybe update the answer, so people can follow up on this. 
Maybe you can provide a "light" version of your code that does some actual work, so people can figure out, how your status bar can be updated.

Comment: All the analyze function does is read a csv that is the filename, do some data cleaning, subtract all the columns by a value and then prints it to an excel sheet.

I could technically break up the code into "steps" and increment a variable or something after each "step" but how would I pass that information back and forth to GUI while analyze is running so the progress bar can be updated